# zooz payment gateway integration in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, woocommerce-rest-api

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I write the code according to the zooz API documentation. View zooz API documentation [here](http://docs.zooz.com/integrations/ecomm/) and my main focus is on this area, I get the paymentToken according to this [image] but from onward to this, I need to get "PaymentMethodToken" by this code given in this [image].

I am doing this integration in javascript and code is following.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.zooz.com"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var initParams = {
            "isSandbox": true,
            uniqueId: "PAPI_ZooZNP_OYMISN3HZ6ZJFL6LSYV4WAYLOQ_5"
        };      
        var zoozApi = new Zooz.Ext.External(initParams);
        var succFunc = function(data) {}
        var failFunc = function(data) {}
        var paymentRequest =
        {
            "paymentToken": "BKS7Y3Y2KD3VWVXKRGVKEXTMGE",
            "email": "johndou@zooz.com",
            "paymentMethod": {
                "paymentMethodType": "CreditCard",
                "paymentMethodDetails": {
                    "cardNumber": "4580458045804580",
                    "month": "08",
                    "year": "17",
                    "cvvNumber": "123"
                }
            }
        };      
        var status = zoozApi.addPaymentMethod(paymentRequest,succFunc, failFunc);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the zooz API documentation [here](http://docs.zooz.com/integrations/ecomm/), you should include the following JavaScript file inside the head section of your web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<Zooz Environment>/mobile/checkoutapi/js/checkout-ext-api.js"></script>
```

Therefore, you should change from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.zooz.com"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.zooz.com/mobile/checkoutapi/js/checkout-ext-api.js"></script>
```